# MongoDB 'Server sockets closed' & no fix found

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

yesterday I started using the javascript MongoDB driver.

I've run into an issue, an error is persistently showing, however, data is still being stored.

Below you can see the javascript I use to initially connect to the DB, and then an insert query is initiated.
When not initiating the insert query, the console outputs:

> Connected correctly to server
>
> Disconnected from server successfully

But when running with the insert query, an error is returned.

> Connected correctly to server
>
> `{ [MongoError: server localhost:27017 sockets closed]` name: 'MongoError',
>
> `message: 'server localhost:27017 sockets closed'}`
>
> Disconnected from server successfully

Could any one point me in the right direction?

```
MongoClient.connect(db_default.db_url, function(err, db) {
    console.log('Connected correctly to server');
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    else {
         mongoInsert(db, 'user', user_default, function(user_res) { 
            console.log(user_res);
        });
    }
    db.close();
    console.log('Disconnected from server successfully');
});

function mongoInsert(db, collection_name, data,cb) {
    var collection = db.collection(collection_name);
    collection.insert(data, function(err, res) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        else {
            console.log('Inserted into the ' + collection_name + ' collection');
            cb(res);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Asynchronicity. Your connect callback calls the insert function and immediately closes the connection to the database before the insert actually runs. Try closing the database connection in the callback from the insert.

Comment: @wdberkeley
So if the connection's getting closed before insert runs, how is the data getting stored?

Comment: @SasankaPanguluri this is non-deterministic, but if the insert occurs then what is happening is that the database driver is dispatching your request off to the database and then closing the connection.  So the database processes the insert but then can't complete the interaction successfully due to the socket having been closed.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Don't Close db connection before receiving results. Do as follow:

```
MongoClient.connect(db_default.db_url, function(err, db) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    else {
         mongoInsert(db, 'user', user_default, function(user_res) { 
            console.log(user_res);
            db.close();
        });
    }

    console.log('Disconnected from server successfully');
});

function mongoInsert(db, collection_name, data,cb) {
    var collection = db.collection(collection_name);
    collection.insert(data, function(err, res) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        else {
            console.log('Inserted into the ' + collection_name + ' collection');
            cb(res);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Asked almost a year ago and I didn't give you the big green tick. Thanks for your help, from the future!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution at last, the problem was file security on the new server and mongdb npm files, I had to use "chown" command to own all files and then run 
 "npm install"